# Docker image with /dev/kvm module

Tags: docker, qemu, kvm

I want to use kvm in my docker image. kvm and qemu-system-x86_64 are installed under /usr/bin but when I run eg. `/usr/bin/qemu-system-x86_64 -enable-kvm`
I'm getting

```
Could not access KVM kernel module: No such file or directory
qemu-system-x86_64: failed to initialize KVM: No such file or directory
```

I was able to fix to error by adding `--device=/dev/kvm` to docker run command.
My question is why this kvm module need to be attached from my host? Why it's required to be under /dev directory?